# Preview canvas for SwiftUI not working, can’t find application bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to iOS development (have done flutter and some react native) and I want to get into making iOS apps.

However I have problems starting the preview canvas. When I start a new project the build completes perfectly when starting the preview canvas but after loading a bit I get this error: "Could not install the preview host "IntervalTraining.app" on iPhone 11 Pro: Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle"

I assume that the preview host can't find the application somehow but whats weird is that when I run the simulator everything works fine and the app installs on the simulator..

I've tried to "Clean Build Folder" but that doesn't work. I've tried to erase all the data on the simulator iPhone and reinstall it on the simulator again and then run the preview canvas but that doesn't work either. I've also tried to delete all the files in the `DerivedData` folder and create new projects multiple times. I've also tried to google the problem but I mostly find questions in Apples developer forum with solutions that I've already tried or doesn't work. And most of the problems I find seem to be linked to react native aswell...

Has anyone else ran into the same problem?

Edit: I'm running XCode 12.2 on Catalina 10.15.6 and a fresh hello world project:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The generated report is this:

```
FailedToInstallAppError: Failed to install "IntervalTraining.app"

Could not install the preview host "IntervalTraining.app" on iPhone 11 Pro

agentBundle = com.andreasjohansson.IntervalTraining {
    url: file:///Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntervalTraining-awlguvqxylziguefdxawcmontfri/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/IntervalTraining/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntervalTraining.app
    version: 8468
    signingInformation: Code Signing {
        identifier: com.andreasjohansson.IntervalTraining
        hasGetTaskAllow: false
        isSandboxed: false
    }
}
udid = AD33D7B1-27B6-4028-BA10-CD2A289EB378
device = iPhone 11 Pro (AD33D7B1-27B6-4028-BA10-CD2A289EB378, iOS 14.2, Booted)

==================================

|  HumanReadableNSError: Failed to install the requested application
|  
|  Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
|  
|  NSPOSIXErrorDomain (2):
|  ==NSLocalizedFailureReason: An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
|  ==bundleURL: file:///Users/andreas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntervalTraining-awlguvqxylziguefdxawcmontfri/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/IntervalTraining/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntervalTraining.app
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you or not.

I had a very similar error from a project I got from a trusted colleague.  After changing the BundleID to mine.  I would get the "agentBundle = " problem.

I cleaned - rebuilt.  Closed & reopended the project.  Finally after closing and restarting XCode - it worked as expected.

Don't know where the problem or solution lies...

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I don't really know what the problem is. But I assume that it is probably something to do with a change I have done to make React Native work. Because when I got a new M1 Mac mini code that didn't work on my old computer worked on the new one..